# Connect to remote MSSQL server with PHP through SSH tunnel

Tags: php, sql-server, ssh

Firewalled MS SQL server wants to supply data to Ubuntu server on the internet.

So I establish an SSH tunnel from the MS SQL server to Ubuntu server, asking Ubuntu to send its `port 1433` traffic to MS SQL's `port 1433`.

According to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/115906/27299) Stack Overflow answer, I think I should be doing this on the MS SQL server:

```
ssh -R 1433:localhost:1433 ubuntu.example.com
```

It's a Windows machine, so I did this in PuTTY:[image]

In the local network, I've tested using PHP  to connect to the SQL server and it works.

```
$server = '192.168.0.12';
$user = 'buttle';
$pass = '1234';
mssql_connect($server,$user,$pass);
```

Now I want to try connecting the same two machines using an SSH tunnel instead of "direct" connection. So I change $server to this:

```
$server = 'localhost,1433';
```

And then I connect an SSH tunnel from the SQL Server machine to the Ubuntu machine with PuTTy. And perhaps this is where I'm going wrong, because I don't know what I'm doing.

[image: PuTTY Tunnels configuration]

I'm getting this PHP error on the Ubuntu machine:

```
Warning: mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server: localhost,1433
```

EDIT:

Also tried this:

[image]

And this:

[![Remote IPv4 with IP address specified in MS SQL server][5]][5]

FINALLY, I have solved it. See my answer.

Comment: Use `IPv4` and the port

Comment: @Sami see EDIT. It doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Did you check `allow remote connections` in your server property?

Comment: Do you mean MS SQL property? I am connecting without SSH tunnel from local network. It stops working when I turn on the tunnel.

Answer (score 2):

All of the online tutorials for using PHP's `mssql` functions assume you are running PHP in a Windows environment. Apparently, in Windows, IP and Port Number are separated by a comma, but in Linux by a colon.

```
// Linux running PHP
$server = 'localhost:1433';
// Windows running PHP
$server = 'localhost,1433';
```

As usual, hours of problems boil down to a single byte.

Comment: That good sir, is a nice piece of investigative coding... Btw - why on earth would they put a comma between ip and port?